# maximum likelihood two unknown parameters

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood

I have a problem. I have to find the mle's (maximum likelihood estimators) for $a$ and $b$ whose density is $f(x|a,b)$, when I derive the $l(b|x)$ (The log-likelihood function) to find the maximum, $b$ is in terms of $a$. But $a$ is unknown.
any suggestions of what to do?

density is $f(x|a,b)=3ax^2+2bx+(1-a-b),~~0<x<1$ and $f$ is decreasing throughout (0,1)

thanks

Comment: The edit helps a lot. Are you asking how to write out the log likelihood function $l(b|x)$ without knowing anything about $a$ yet?

Comment: No, how find how find b? and a.

Comment: $f$ is obviously not a density: for various values of $a,b,$ and $x$, it will be negative and it certainly does not integrate to unity! Please tell us what the restrictions on the variables are.

Comment: these are the values ​​of x: $0<x<1$

Comment: And what about $a$ and $b$?  Are these perhaps non-negative with a sum not exceeding $1$? Or are other values allowed?  Why don't you just solve for $a$ and $b$ directly, as is usual in MLE?

Comment: say $3ax^2+2bx+(1−a−b) $  is decreasing throughout (0,1)

Comment: That implies $(a,b)$ lies within a triangular region with vertices at $(-1/2,0)$, $(0,0)$, and $(1,-3)$.  Thus, you maximize the likelihood subject to these constraints.

Comment: could you explain how to obtain the a triangular region? and how maximize the likelihood ?  because $b$ is in terms of $a$. But $a$ is unknown. I'm confused

Answer (score 2):

This answer goes through the minimal amount of analysis to discern the nature of the problem, find a solution method, and identify potential problems or limitations.  In the end, you will need to use numerical methods to maximize the likelihood.

---

In order for any function to be a density, it has to integrate to $1$ and be nonnegative throughout its domain, which here is $[0,1]$.  When we add the requirement that it be decreasing, we obtain a set of *linear* conditions on the parameters $a$ and $b$:

1. $1 = \int_0^1 f(x) dx$ automatically.
2. $1-a-b = f(0) \ge f(1) = 3a + 2b + 1-a-b = 1 + 2a + b \ge 0$.
3. $6a x + 2b = f^\prime(x) \le 0$ for $x\in [0,1]$, so in particular $2b = f^\prime(0) \le 0$ and $6a + 2b = f^\prime(1) \le 0$.

Conditions (2) and (3) determine five half-planes in $(a,b)$ coordinates.  Their intersection is a triangle with vertices at $(-1,0)$,$(0,0)$, and $(1,3)$, as shown in the figure.

[image: Figure]

This is the set of possible values of the parameters.  Its boundary consists of portions of the zeros of three functions which are negative on the interior:

$$\cases{g_1(a,b) = 3a + b \\ g_2(a,b) = b \\ g_3(a,b) = -(2a + b + 1).}$$

Given iid data $\mathbf{x}=(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ drawn from such a distribution, the log likelihood of $(a,b)$ is (by definition) the logarithm of the probability of $\mathbf{x}$.  It depends on the unknown value $(a,b)$:

$$\Lambda(a,b|\mathbf{x}) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log f(x_i|a,b) = \sum_{i=1}^n \log \left(3ax_i^2 + 2b x_i + 1-a-b\right).$$

Critical points $(a,b)$ satisfy the [KKT conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions): there must exist constants $\mu_1, \mu_2, \mu_3$ such that

$$D f(a,b) = \mu_1 D g_1(a,b) + \mu_2 D g_2(a,b) + \mu_3 D g_3(a,b).\tag{1}$$

(There are additional conditions that amount to asserting that $(a,b)$ lies within the triangle, the $\mu_i$ are non-negative, and each product $\mu_i g_i(a,b)$ is zero.)

The derivatives are readily computed:

$$\eqalign{
D f(a,b) &= \left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}(a,b), \frac{\partial f}{\partial b}(a,b)\right)^\prime \\
&= \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{3x_i^2 - 1}{3ax_i^2 + 2b x_i + 1-a-b}, \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{2x_i - 1}{3ax_i^2 + 2b x_i + 1-a-b}\right)^\prime; \\
Dg_1(a,b) &= (3,1)^\prime; \\
Dg_2(a,b) &= (0,1)^\prime;\\
Dg_3(a,b) &= (2,1)^\prime.
}$$

When the algebra is performed and a common denominator is found, the numerators in $(1)$ become high-degree polynomials in $a$ and $b$: **you need to solve this one numerically.**  When you do, you will obtain at least one $(a,b)$ for which $\Lambda$ is maximized.  If one or more of the $\mu_i$ are nonzero (and any constrained optimizer will tell whether this is so), then the solution is on the boundary and special techniques are needed to develop confidence intervals for the estimates.

Comment: Care to elaborate on the special techniques to develop confidence intervals for the estimates in the event of a boundary solution? Can you do something like using inverse of Hessian projected into nullspace of active constraints at solution?